# How to strip the Year from a DateTime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have two columns in a table.

- FinancialYear (DATETIME :  2011-05-01 00:00:00.000)
- PostingYear (INT: currently empty)

I want to populate the empty column using the year from the `FinancialYear` column, incremented by one.

For example, I want: PostingYear = FinancialYear + 1, giving me just the year `2012` from `2011-05-01 00:00:00.000` value without months and day.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: With the [Year()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function (bot in MySQL and MSSS)?

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Both MySQL and SQL Server now support the `YEAR()` function.

MySQL:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

SQL Server:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx

SQL Server also supports `DATEPART()`:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add `computed column` in `ms SQL`
Use the flowing `formula` for column
for example if date column is fdate use

```
Year(fdate)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the Year, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT YEAR(FinancialYear)
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

Then adding 1:

```
SELECT YEAR(FinancialYear) + 1
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

To run an `UPDATE` on your table you can do the following:

```
UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE]
SET PostingYear = YEAR(FinancialYear) + 1
```

This will strip the **Year** from your `FinancialYear` column and add 1 and insert all of the values in to your empty column - `PostingYear`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I have been trying to achieve!

Comment: @Pavel No problem, feel free to upvote and mark the answer if this solved your problem.